# How do I dynamically define help for a hubot command?

Tags: coffeescript, hubot

Hubot generally expects scripts to have headers of the form:

```
# Commands:
#   hubot foo - Hubot says foo.
```

However, what if I want to dynamically define the text trigger for my command? E.g. if I have a command:

```
fooCommandText = process.env.HUBOT_FOO_COMMAND || 'foo'

module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.respond ///#{fooCommandText}///, (response) ->
    response.send 'foo'
```

I still want `hubot help` to work, but I can't use a static header to define what my command looks like.

Looking at robot.coffee in Hubot itself, I can see `parseHelp` explicitly reads the script file and parses the header.

How can I make `hubot help` work for a command whose text trigger is dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append to `robot.commands` instead of defining a help block:

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.commands.push "hubot #{fooCommandText} - Hubot says foo."
```